# Asp.Net Web Api 2.2: A null 'MediaTypeFormatter' is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I'm having a few issues with a Asp.Net Web Api application in our production environment, some api requests (about 1% of them) crash intermittently with the following exception message:

*A null 'MediaTypeFormatter' is not valid.
Parameter name: formatters*

All these errors seem to happen randomly and in these cases the execution flow doesn't even reach the ApiController endpoints.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

More infos and complete stacktrace:

- .Net Framework 4.5
- Asp.Net Web Api 2.2 (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi package v5.2.3)
- IIS 8.5
- Windows server 2012 R2

```
"ExceptionMessage": "A null 'MediaTypeFormatter' is not valid.
Parameter name: formatters",
"ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.VerifyAndSetFormatters(IEnumerable'1 formatters)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable'1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable'1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable'1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

EDIT 04/05/2020

- Our production environment configuration is 7 servers under a load
  balancer
- Only one application pool of a single server presented the
  problem
- After recycling the application the problem disappeared (we
  are still investigating the issue, we don't want it to happen again).

Comment: I'm not sure if you can tell or know, but are the failing requests made with a content-type header of something other than XML or JSON? Also, do you attempt to load any custom formatters during initialisation?

Comment: @Craig H unfortunately I'm not able to tell you  if requests were made with another content-type. I can confirm some controllers have a custom logic that overrides the ApiController Initialize method and replaces the controller default JsonTypeFormatter with a new one with custom SerializerSettings. The strange thing is we got this error even on endpoints which don't use the replaced JsonTypeFormatter. I have edited my answer because after refreshing the application pool the problem seems to have disappeared (we are still investigating the issue)